# Could this script be shortened using "While" loop in Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script

Currently have this code

```
cmb1BuyValue1 = ta.valuewhen(nz(cmb1Buy[1]) == 0, close, 0)
cmb1BuyValue2 = ta.valuewhen(nz(cmb1Buy[1]) == 1, close, 0)
...
cmb1BuyValue(n) = ta.valuewhen(nz(cmb1Buy[1]) == (n-1), close, 0)

if sinceCmb1Buy < sinceBuyNine
    if nz(cmb1Buy[1]) == 1
        if buyCmbCond and close <= cmb1BuyValue1
            nz(cmb1Buy[1]) + 1
        else
            nz(cmb1Buy[1])
    else
        if nz(cmb1Buy[1]) == 2
            if buyCmbCond and close <= cmb1BuyValue2
                nz(cmb1Buy[1]) + 1
            else
                nz(cmb1Buy[1])
        ...
        else
            if nz(cmb1Buy[1]) == (n)
                if buyCmbCond and close <= cmb1BuyValue(n)
                    nz(cmb1Buy[1]) + 1
                else
                    nz(cmb1Buy[1])
```

This goes until n = 9.

How can I shorten this code using "For loops" or "while loops"??

New to coding in general, thank you very much

Comment: What do you do with all those if checks? There is no assignment. Is this body of a function?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it's a body of a function, forgot to include it on there